# Need a help to establish the connection between content server and sap server using archive link

Tags: httpserver, sap-basis, fileserver

I am new to `SAP`, and I am trying my hands on `storing` the `sap archived files` on a `content server` or `archive server` using an `archive link`. So we have a `SAP server` installed on a `Windows` machine, and we have another `Linux` machine on the `same network` with `Apache` installed on it. (`Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (CentOS Stream)`). So when I am trying to create an `Archive link`, it's asking to specify the `SAP Content Server` `Version` and `HTTP Script`, which I don't have because I don't have them installed on my `Linux` machine as a `content server` or `archive server`.

[image]

Now, when I am trying to create an `archive link` by specifying a `0046` as the `content server version` and a `ddl` path that doesn't exist, it's throwing an `HTTP error 404: Not found`.

[image]

If we want to connect the `content server` to `SAP` via an `archive link`, is it necessary for us to install the `SAP Content Server` and `SAP Cache Server` `software` on the `content server`? Is there any alternative to this?